# how to call custom method automatically in global.asax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my code and i want to call the my custom method (`Application_My()`) automatically when application is loaded/refresh every time like `Application_OnEndRequest()`.

Thanks in advance.

```
<%@ Application  Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">

    // THis code will be executed automatically when page is reloaded everytime
/*protected void Application_OnEndRequest()
{

    Response.Write("Thsi page is executed on=" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
}*/

    // how to call below method automatically when page is reloaded everytime
    //such as above
    protected void Application_My()
    {
        Response.Write("Hi welcome");
    }


    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: what issue are you running into?

Comment: its very unclear what you ask for. The application can only start and stop, not reload or refresh.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application_My();
}
```

However, note that this is called for everything that is managed by your aspnet pipeline, so you might get called on css and image requests.

You could add Debug.WriteLine(Request.Url); to the code above to see what happens when you enter your site.